# Cordova/jQuery Mobile origin null is not allowed on localhost

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm building a web app based on Cordova (Phonegap) and jQuery Mobile. Since I'm fetching data with Ajax, I added an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to my dynamic content served by my web server. This is working great.

Since I don't want to use a single template layout, I created multiple files linked in my footer navbar. They live in my /www folder on localhost (the phone). Whenever I use the link in my navbar to one of those pages, I get an `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` error. How can I fix that?

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a data-icon="star" href="start.html">start</a></li>
      <li><a data-icon="grid" href="list.html">list</a></li>
      <li><a data-icon="alert" href="alert.html">alert</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: 
You need to set **$.support.cors** and **$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages** values to true.

"Your ability to access cross-domain pages from within a Phone Gap jQuery Mobile application is controlled by two key things: **$.support.cors** and **$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages**, and can also be influenced by the white list feature in later builds of PhoneGap."

Read more at http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html

Option 2:
I am guessing you may not want to use this, but it is an option to turn off Ajax Link behaviour by using **data-ajax="false"** with your  tag.